# Swift equivalent of String.format and .Replace?

Tags: java, ios, swift

I have the snippet of java code.

```
functionReturnValue = String.format("%1$2s", jDay).replace(' ', '0') + "/" + String.format("%1$2s", i).replace(' ', '0') + "/" + dateIn.substring(0, 4);
```

What is the swift equivalent of this?
This is what I have so far

```
let string1 = String(format: "%1$2s", jDay);
let replacedString = String(string1.characters.map{$0 == " " ? "0" : $0})
let string2 = String(format: "%1$2s", i);
let replacedString2 = String(string2.characters.map{$0 == " " ? "0" : $0})
let string3 = dateIn[year];
let stringFinal = replacedString + "/" + replacedString2 + "/" + string3;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format strings in Swift and in Java are different, so you cannot use `%1$2s` for your format. Also, since the call of `replace` in your Java code is there to add leading zeros, you could replace it with a call of format. Finally, use [*string interpolation*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292) to construct the final string:

```
let s1 = String(format: "%02d", jDay)
let s2 = String(format: "%02d", i)
let s3 = dateIn[year]
let stringFinal = "\(s1)/\(s2)/\(s3)"
```

Comment: I just got into swift from java. Looks like I still need to learn some new syntaxes. Thank you for the insight!

Comment: In case anyone else looks at this and thinks that you need to format one value at a time, that's not the case.  For example:

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is wondering (like I was) you can have format strings with multiple conversions, e.g.:

```
let hourPart = 5
let minutePart = 8
let isPm = true
let retStr = String(format: "%d:%02d %@", hourPart, minutePart, isPm ? "PM" : "AM")
```

gives "5:08 PM"